# how to pass data from sectioned table view to detail view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist

Ive recently downloaded Jeff LaMarche`s sectioned table view and Im trying to implement a detail view. Problem is I dont know what to put on my didSelectRow and on viewDidLoad from detailView.m. Im using a plist for this.

This is how my table view is configured:
Code:

```
//SectionsViewController.h

    NSDictionary *allNames;
    NSMutableDictionary *names;
    NSMutableArray       *keys;

//SectionsViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sortednames" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.allNames = dict; [dict release]; }

//on cellForRowAtIndexPath:

        NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];   
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];

        cell.textLabel.text =  [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"] ;

       return cell;

//on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

       NSString *selectedItem =[[nameSection objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Title"];

       Detail *dvController = [[Detail alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    dvController.selectedItem = selectedItem;

    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
    NSLog(@"teste1");


//Detail.m

NSDictionary *details = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sortednames" ofType:@"plist"]];

details = [details objectForKey:self.selectedItem];

titleLabel.text = [selectedItem objectForKey:@"Title"];
descriptionLabel.text = [selectedItem objectForKey:@"description"];
```

my plist is like this:
Code:

```
<dict>
    <key>3 jan</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>asdf</string>
            <key>description</key>
            <string>asdqqq</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>4 Jan</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>asddww</string>
            <key>description</key>
            <string>asdd</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?
any help is appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way of passing the details to your Details controller. A couple of options is using a property or a custom initializer.

```
//Detail.h
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle details:(NSString*)details;
    //And/or
@property(copy) NSString *details;
```

Original Code

```
//on didSelectRowAtIndexPath
NSString *selectedItem =[[nameSection objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
Detail *dvController = [[Detail alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.details = selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

**Edit**

You may have other issues and one may be that you are trying to get `objectForKey:` using @"Title" and that is incorrect if you have not drilled into the dates yet. Your PLIST is a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries. Here is an example of accessing a value from your array.

```
NSArray *values = [dictionary objectForKey:@"3 Jan"];
NSDictionary *anyValue = [values lastObject];
NSString *title = [anyValue objectForKey:@"Title"];
NSString *description = [anyValue objectForKey:@"description"];
```